# httpsconnectionpool to extract the api

Tags: python, pandas, api, request

Hi i am trying to run this code but it is not working i am getting this error message

HTTPSConnectionPool(host='population.un.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /dataportalapi/api/v1/locations/ (Caused by ProxyError('Cannot connect to proxy.', ConnectionResetError(10054, 'An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host', None, 10054, None)))

```
    import pandas as pd
    import json
    import requests

    # Declares the base URL for calling API
    base_url = "https://population.un.org/dataportalapi/api/v1"

    # Creates the target URL, indicators, in this instance
    target = base_url + "/locations/"

    # Calls the API
    response = requests.get(target)

    # Converts call into JSON
    j = response.json()

    # Converts JSON into a pandas DataFrame.
    df = pd.json_normalize(j) # pd.json_normalize flattens the JSON to accomodate nested lists within the JSON structure

    # Alternatively, a user can have the same results returned in a CSV format and import them directly using pandas.read_csv()
    df2 = pd.read_csv(target+"?format=csv")

#To view response code:

    print(response)

    ## <Response [200]>
```

Comment: The code as shown in your question doesn't work. It fails at pd.read_csv. If you look at the csv file in your favourite browser you'll see why. If I remove the offending line, your code runs. Can you please show the code that induces the error that you're seeing?

Comment: it fails at this line of code   response = requests.get(target)

Comment: Works for me. Have you tried it from a browser? You may have been blacklisted

Answer (score 0):

I think your url_base contains an error. Try adding '.0' at the end

base_url = "https://population.un.org/dataportalapi/api/v1.0"